# Refactoring Grails command validation

Tags: grails, groovy

In my application, I have a lot of code like the following:

```
def add(CreatePersonCommand command) {
    if(command.hasErrors()) {
        redirect(action: 'add')
        return
    }
}
```

I'm not a fan of this duplication, so I'd like to refactor it. I was hoping Grails would have something like the following:

```
@Validate(action:'someAction')
def add(CreatePersonCommand command) {

}
```

Or

```
def add(@Valid CreatePersonCommand command) {
}
```

Which would autovalidate the command, and redirect to a GSP in case there are errors. I tried creating something like this with interceptors and filters, but I failed, since I cannot get access to the action and the command in the filter.

Maybe I'm missing something, but is there a better way to handle this, or implement something like the above?

Comment: No such feature exists.  It would be easy to implement.  If I were going to do it I would write an AST transformation that does it.  All of the current command object handling is imposed by an AST transformation.

Comment: In your example the `add` action redirects to itself if the command object has errors.  Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to think about how this could be made generally useful and I am not sure.  You said "Which would autovalidate the command, and redirect to a GSP in case there are errors.".  Is it the case that you mean `render` and if so, would you expect the command object to be in the model, possibly with whatever name was used for the original controller action argument name?

Comment: I am asking because I am considering what kinds of things we can do in Grails core to improve this.  It might be generally useful to offer something like a mechanism to specify a view to render if the command object has errors and maybe other options.  Possibly also providing some mechanism for you to provide a handler of your own that is invoked any time a command object has errors and you could do whatever arbitrary stuff you wanted to do.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, You could add this comment as an answer :)

Comment: I didn't leave it as an answer because it isn't really an answer, at least not the kind of answer that is beneficial to StackOverflow. I don't think the question is particularly useful to StackOverflow either. It is setup as a question but is really just the initiation of a discussion about possibilities which is better suited for the Grails group at http://groups.google.com/d/forum/grails-dev-discuss.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for your comments. I thought this was a technical question about how to do this in Grails, therefor not suitable for the dev mailing list. You're right of course about the redirect to the 'add', that was a mistake: it should redirect to a view whenever an error occurs. Which AST transformation takes care of this right now?

Comment: " it should redirect to a view whenever an error occurs.  Which AST transformation takes care of this right now?" There is no AST transformation which takes care of this right now.  This functionality does not exist in Grails.

Comment: Hi Jeff, sorry for being unclear: you said the command objects are done by an AST transformation. I was referring to that AST: which AST takes care of handling commands right now?

Comment: The right way is to use the filter chain of grails. In the filter you have the params scope so you can create an instance of your CommandObject. def objValidator = YourCommandObject(params)

Comment: Giuseppe, that won't work: how do I know which command object to instantiate? It depends on the action I'm executing.

Comment: @ErikPragt did you file a feature request in our JIRA instance?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I don't think I did.

Comment: Ok in your filters you can't have a Command but you got params map.
So you can do  something like:
def person = new CreatePersonCommand(params) and
if (person.hasErrors() ) do some stuff...

Comment: How do you know it's a CreatePersonCommand, and not RemovePersonCommand?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - I have created a feature request on githb https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/603

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account at the comments in the question, I came up with a temporal workaround.

Having a Command like:

```
@grails.validation.Validateable
class FooCommand implements Serializable {
    String username
    String email
    static constraints = {
        username nullable: false, blank: false, minSize: 6
        email email: true, nullable: false, blank: false
    }
}
```

And a Controller with the action `index` to execute only if params validate the command object and the action `error` to redirect to in case of validation errors:

```
class FooController {
    def index() {
        render 'ok!'
    }
    def error() {
        render 'errors = ' + params.errors
    }
}
```

Then, you can define a Filter for all requests (or the ones you want) and according to the controller and action that the request is trying to go, you can validate the command object with the desired params like this:

```
class FooFilters {
    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {
                if (params.controller == 'foo' && (!params.action || params.action == 'index')) {
                    FooCommand cmd = new FooCommand(params.subMap(['username','email']))
                    if (!cmd.validate()) {
                        redirect controller: 'foo', action: 'error', params: [errors:cmd.errors]
                        return false
                    }
                }
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code can be improved in many ways. But I think it's enough as an example solution.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you asked for I wrote a plugin, that does something similar. It Uses and AST to add a handler, it also enhances the controllers with a default handler if none is provided. However the handler is given only command objects that have Command, as the last part of there name, as the plugin also tries to give command object more convention.

http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/virtualdogbert/command